# how can i show console.log this situation?

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js, reactjs

hi i want to show console.log this situation..

if lasdId value is {}

i want to show console.log("hello");

but it doesn't work... how can i fix my code??

this is my code

```
    router.post('/related', async (req, res, next) => {
      
      try {
        // const lastId = parseInt(req.query.lastId, 10);
      const lastId = req.body;
      console.log("lastId:::::::::::::::::::::::",lastId);
    

      if (lastId === {}) {
        console.log("hello!");
        // where.id = { [Op.in]: followings.map((v) => v.id).filter(value => value < lastId)}
        // console.log("where:::::::::::::::::",where);
      }
```

i think the reason why console.log doesn't show up is that lastID type is uncorrect... then how can i fix type?

Comment: The value of lastId is not {}, so the log is ignored

Comment: then how can i fix?? undefinde??

Comment: what's the value of lastId?

Comment: It seems that the condition never applies, console.log(lastId) just before the if statement, then you would probably understand why the log(hello) doesnt appear.

Comment: Yeah, you should try what MrJami suggested

Comment: check if `Object.keys`. `if (Object.keys(last).length === 0) { console.log("Hello");}`

Comment: #@souravsatyam thank you i understand!!!!!